# How to change the font and size of text editor in Blender 2.8?

Tags: interface

I played with the Blender Preference in Blender 2.8, but did not find any way to change the actual font/size used inside the text editor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change it in the sidebar of the text editor, which you can open with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> or *View > Sidebar*. The font size can also be adjusted without opening the sidebar by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and using the scroll wheel.

[image: Sidebar]

Comment: @lemon thanks for the edit. Missed the CTRL somehow.

Comment: ... and Ctrl-Scroll will change the size..

Comment: Thanks, it is so easy to change the font size!  How about the font, I want to use a mono font with different look-and-feel of 0, O, 1, I, l. (zero, oh, one, eye, ell)

Comment: @user1492549 that can be changed in the preferences. *Edit > Preferences > Interface > Text Rendering*.

Comment: Thanks! It is not obvious though.

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted by clicking on the checkmark if it solved your problem.